# Vuejs пустая и заполненная форма

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, vuex

Делаю одностраничное приложение. На странице есть несколько форм, каждая из которых позволяет добавлять информацию в БД. И формы эти между собой связаны - сначала заполняешь одну, потом вторую и т.п. Одновременно с этим можно загрузить данные из БД в эти формы для редактирования и последующего обновления этих данных в БД.

Каждую форму я вынес в компонент. Для реактивности полям в форме назначил `:value=""`. Если в Хранилище (vuex) есть данные, то они будут загружены в эти поля. Но как быть, когда данных в харнилище нет? Возникает резонная ошибка и компонент не отображается.

Ближе к сущностям. На странице есть форма для регистрации данных человека: ФИО, адрес и др. В хранилище две переменные:

- `person` - для данных пользователя, которые получим из БД и которыми нужно будет автоматически заполнить форму + данные человека, которые сюда попадут из формы при нажатии кнопки "добавить" (а затем будут записаны в БД).
- `person_id` - переменная для идентификатора человека, данные которого следует загрузить из БД (и заполнить ими форму). Если пусто тут, значит форма пустая.

Код предаставлен ниже:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            person_id: 120,
            person: {},
        },
```

Таким образом планирую использовать одну форму и для создания новых записей. И для загрузки\редактирования существующих.

Но как быть с тем, что форма изначально при загрузке страницы пустая? Т.к. она пустая, а в форме проставлены `:value="person.surname"` и т.д., то возникает ошибка. И компонент (форма) вовсе не отображается.

Неужели единственное решение - вручную прописывать пустой объект по умолчанию в хранилище? Или есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказано в документации:

> Vue не может отследить добавление или удаление свойства объекта. Чтобы
>   поле стало реактивным, Vue превращает его в пару геттер/сеттер в ходе
>   инициализации экземпляра.

Чтобы динамически добавить реактивное свойство, вам необходимо использовать метод:

```
Vue.set(this.object, key, value)
```

или

```
this.$set(this.object, key, value)
```

> Иногда нужно добавить несколько свойств в существующий объект,
>   например, с помощью Object.assign() или _.extend()

В данном случае документация советует использовать следующий метод:

```
this.object = Object.assign({}, this.object, { key1: value1, key2: value2 })
```

Поскольку

> Vuex — это реактивная переменная Vue

производить мутации по добавлению новых свойств у объекта вам необходимо тем же способом, что и в самом Vue.

Подробнее прочитайте в [разделе документации Vue "Подробно о реактивности"](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) и в [разделе документации Vuex "Мутации"](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/mutations.html)

Comment: А можно более конретизировать? Т.е. получается, изначально к полям формы у меня не добавлены никакие "реактивные свойства". А уже после получения данных я к этим input должен добавить реактивность? А как в методе получить определённый imput и назначить ему реактивное value?

Comment: Нет, добавлять реактивность к input вам не нужно. 

Вы можете поступить следующим образом - поля формы в самой форме задавать в цикле, например: `<input type="text" v-for="input in person" :key="input.id" :value="input.value">` и поскольку свойства, которые вы будете создавать, способом, как было описано в ответе выше - они будут становится реактивными и автоматически отобразятся в вашей форме.

Можете посмотреть на примере [TodoMVC из документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/examples/todomvc.html) , когда элемент добавляется, он автоматически отображается в списке.

Comment: Мг. Но в форме  у меня есть input text, date, select, range... Получается, что где-то на сервере нужно ещё хранить какого типа какие поля?

Comment: Как вариант да, можно хранить на сервере и в соответствие с этим типом данные расставлять. Другой вариант, типы input (которые вам нужны) описать в коде, и в зависимости от поступающих данных подставлять нужные.

Comment: А чем всё это тогда проще\отличается от того, чтобы сразу прописать все пустые переменные?

Comment: Прописывая пустые переменные, вы привязываетесь к ним, и вам необходимо будет (если что то поменяется в бэке) каждый раз создавать новые пустые переменные (либо же изменять как то старые). А если вы будете создавать их динамически, то вы не будете зависеть от того, поменялось в бэке что-либо или нет. С другой стороны, если вы уверены, что бэк будет всегда один и тот же, вы можете сразу все прописать в переменные.